# Picker Tool for 4D data (2D x 2D)

Tags: dm-script

Does there exist a (free) solution for extracting 2D slices from a 4D dataset? I'm thinking of something like the EELS SI Picker tool, or the DM-script one in [Dave Mitchell's SITools](http://www.dmscripting.com/sitools.html) package. I can currently change the slice being viewed on my 4D data in GMS 3 using the [Gatan-provided SI Viewer](https://www.gatan.com/installation-instructions), but I'm unable to manipulate it in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To answer the *scripting* question:
>
> It could be done by scripting and listener scripts, yes.
> **But there is no need to.**.

The 4D picker tool in GMS 3 is already free, but you need to use the appropriate free license.
When you go to [Gatan's webpage for the free offline GMS](https://www.gatan.com/installation-instructions) you get various choices.
You need the STEMx lincense for the 4D picker tool. See below.

**Note that you can use multiple licenses side-by-side, so I would recommend to get the last two or three.**

---

[image]

Comment: Well, this is substantially more convenient than what I expected! Thank you very much!